# "but" usage (redundancy of "but")

Tags: lexical-semantics, phrase-structure, clauses, lexical-relations

We all know that "but" is used to replace "except" or indicate that the first clause is contrastive to the second in a way, or the logic these two sentences bear is somewhat contradictory. But, I see that there is also a redundant use of "but". I want to confirm whether it is a form of redundancy, or it is just me. Please consider the following:

1. I am not a teacher, BUT I am a student.
2. It is not a gun, BUT it is a curtain.
3. He is not a president, BUT he is a clown.

Comment: _But_ means the same thing as _and_ in logic. The only difference between them is a presupposition of surprise about the clause introduced by _but_. That surprise can be for any reason -- semantic, situational, personal, pragmatic -- and it is up to the addressee to figure out what it stems from. It is certainly not redundant, except in the sense that _but_ is logically equivalent to _and_ -- `A` _and_ `B` has the same truth value as `A` _but_ `B`.

Comment: In my experience languages differ in terms of what counts as a contrast / opposition / reason for surprise. I realise, thinking about the sentences above, that when the but is basically concessive (*we need a guy who is both a president and a clown / well I know someone - he's not a president, but he is a clown*) the *he is* goes in, whereas when the reason is that a presupposition is being contradicted (*it turned out that he was not a president, but a clown*), it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered your own question!

> "but" is used to […] indicate that the first clause is contrastive to the second in a way

In your first example, "I am not a teacher" contrasts with "I am a student". In context, I'd imagine something like this:

> Alice, in a school: Excuse me, are you a teacher? I have some questions about the organization here.
>   Bob: I'm not a teacher… *[and thus might not be able to answer]*
>   Bob: …but I am a student. *[and thus **can** answer]*

In other words, the "but" is because the implication of the first part is the opposite of the implication of the second part.

In your other two examples, I wouldn't use "but" in most cases: only in a context where the two clauses had different implicatures (like above).

Answer (score 0):

The examples you are given are not natural, although maybe formally correct. Colloquially, you'll rather find

> I am not a teacher, but a student

where *but* is adverbially linking *student* to the verb of the matrix clause We can readily see that *I am not a student, [and] a teacher* is ambiguous; different bracketing yields different ways to parse the negation; If anything, the intended negation is ungrammatical because the number of the singular subject disagrees with the two-headed object. Redundancy is thus required to disambiguate, e.g: *I am not a student, not a teacher*, which however is equally unlikely, and rather said using *neither, nor*. The base case *I am a student, [and] a teacher [and a unicorn]* is still ambiguous due to the semantics, where teacher and student are usually in opposition, so *as well as* might be used as the conjunction of choice to mark simultanity. Copula are regularly required between two indefinite nouns, except for adpositions (*a teacher, a smart one*).

The only thing that's redundant in your example is the repeated verb. If *amn't* is parsed as a lexeme, then *I am not X, I am Y* is anaphoric without redundancy. However, that's rarely the case, as shown in the frequent reversal *I am a Y, not an X*.

There's another reason to use the conjunction: *It is not the show it ..." rather expects "... used to be", a syntax that can be explicitly disambiguited with the conjunction *that*. It seems reasonable to assume the indefinite article would follow the same pattern of the definite article, for simplicity of the paradigm, even if a definite pronoun *it* cannot be in adposition to an indefinite noun (rather it needs *that*, which then functions as a determiner: *It is not a show that is shown on TV*). Moving out on a limb I guess we may still see *It will not rain, it won't*, which is prefectly redundant, that is seen all too frequently in reversed order in anaphoric questions, *isn't it*?

Comment: *_Amn't_ has never been an English lexeme afaik. The attested contraction of _am not_ is _ain't_, though it's become stigmatized (and in some dialects generalized to other persons).

Comment: That aside, though, (as a native speaker) "I'm not a teacher, but I *am* a student" (with emphasis) seems perfectly natural. "I am not a teacher, but a student" sounds much more formal and somewhat stilted.

Answer (score 0):

The examples that you picked are where `but` is simply being a conjunction joining 2 sentences/clauses. The usage of `but` there seems redundant for that reason but (note the meta usage of the very word here) without it you'll have 2 separate sentences. So you'd have to say

> I am not a teacher. I am a student

or with the conjunction

> I am not a teacher but a student

There is still a possibility for a different question. Perhaps a parent looking for some employee of the school for some help with directions could ask, "Are you a teacher?"

> I am not a teacher but I could help.

Note, the second part is not even contrasting the first. Again, without the `but`

> I am not a teacher. I could help.

It is still not redundancy much like other conjunctions aren't.